# sql error handling and output

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, error-handling

I have the below code which iterates through each row and runs the stored proc for each value in the row. Some values fail and the code goes on to the next value till it has run the SP for the entire table.

What I need to know is how to generate a list of all the rows it tried and failed on. I dont want it to stop when it fails as it should complete, but it should let me know the rowsID which it didnt work for, so I can run it again just for the failed rows.

```
    DECLARE @SP VARCHAR(50)
    DECLARE @ROWID INT
    DECLARE @MAXROW INT
    DECLARE @HEADOFFICECLIENTINVOICEID VARCHAR(50)
    DECLARE @OUTLETID VARCHAR(50)
    DECLARE @COMPANYINFOID VARCHAR(50)
    DECLARE @YEARID VARCHAR(50)
    DECLARE @AREAID VARCHAR(50)
    DECLARE @REPORTSTYLE VARCHAR(50)
    DECLARE @STARTDATE VARCHAR(50)
    DECLARE @ENDDATE VARCHAR(50)
    DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(1000)

    SET @SP = 'FINANCE_BUDGETING_AGAINST_ACTUAL_REPORT'
    SET @ROWID = 1

    SELECT @MAXROW = MAX(ROWID)
    FROM #AKTEMP

    WHILE @ROWID <= @MAXROW
    BEGIN
        SELECT @HEADOFFICECLIENTINVOICEID = HEADOFFICECLIENTINVOICESID
        FROM #AKTEMP
        WHERE ROWID = @ROWID

        SELECT @OUTLETID = OUTLETID
        FROM #AKTEMP
        WHERE ROWID = @ROWID

        SELECT @COMPANYINFOID = COMPANYINFOID
        FROM #AKTEMP
        WHERE ROWID = @ROWID

        SELECT @YEARID = YEARID
        FROM #AKTEMP
        WHERE ROWID = @ROWID

        SELECT @AREAID = AREAID
        FROM #AKTEMP
        WHERE ROWID = @ROWID

        SELECT @REPORTSTYLE = REPORTSTYLE
        FROM #AKTEMP
        WHERE ROWID = @ROWID

        SELECT @STARTDATE = CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), REPORTDATEFROM, 106)
        FROM #AKTEMP
        WHERE ROWID = @ROWID

        SELECT @ENDDATE = CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), REPORTDATETO, 106)
        FROM #AKTEMP
        WHERE ROWID = @ROWID

        SET @SQL = @SP + ' @HEADOFFICECLIENTINVOICEID = ' + @HEADOFFICECLIENTINVOICEID +
                        ', @OUTLETID = ' + @OUTLETID + 
                        ', @COMPANYINFOID = ' + @COMPANYINFOID + 
                        ', @YEARID = ' + @YEARID + 
                        ', @AREAID = ' + @AREAID + 
                        ', @REPORTSTYLE = ' + @REPORTSTYLE + 
                        ', @STARTDATE = ''' + @STARTDATE + '''' + 
                        ', @ENDDATE = ''' + @ENDDATE + ''''

        PRINT @SQL
        PRINT @ROWID

        EXEC (@SQL)

        SET @ROWID = @ROWID + 1
    END
```

Comment: Why not just put the IDs of the rows that failed in a table ..?

Comment: Hi, Yes that would work. but I dont know what code I would type that would identify the failed ID's as oppose to the successful ones.

Comment: you can set all values with a single select statement, e.g.: `select @OutletID = OuletID, @AreaID = AreaID, @... from #AKTemp where rowid=@rowid`

Comment: you can even build whole script with a single select : `select @sql += '@OutletID=' + cast(OutletID as varchar(10)) + ', ' + ...`

Comment: Thank you thats made the query much better

Comment: Also you don't need dynamic part at all. `EXEC @SP @OutledID = @OutletID, @Startdate = @StartDate`

Comment: appended approach with no dynamic sql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I handled with Try  Catch Error handling. And If error comes it will capture rowid in Table variable @TAB.

Note: I have not checked it as no schema available for your case.

```
    DECLARE @SP VARCHAR(50)
    DECLARE @ROWID INT
    DECLARE @MAXROW INT
    DECLARE @HEADOFFICECLIENTINVOICEID VARCHAR(50)
    DECLARE @OUTLETID VARCHAR(50)
    DECLARE @COMPANYINFOID VARCHAR(50)
    DECLARE @YEARID VARCHAR(50)
    DECLARE @AREAID VARCHAR(50)
    DECLARE @REPORTSTYLE VARCHAR(50)
    DECLARE @STARTDATE VARCHAR(50)
    DECLARE @ENDDATE VARCHAR(50)
    DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(1000)

    SET @SP = 'FINANCE_BUDGETING_AGAINST_ACTUAL_REPORT'
    SET @ROWID = 1

    SELECT @MAXROW = MAX(ROWID)
    FROM #AKTEMP

    DECLARE @TAB TABLE (
        SNO INT IDENTITY
        ,ROWID INT
        )

    WHILE @ROWID <= @MAXROW
    BEGIN
        BEGIN TRY
            SELECT @HEADOFFICECLIENTINVOICEID = HEADOFFICECLIENTINVOICESID
            FROM #AKTEMP
            WHERE ROWID = @ROWID

            SELECT @OUTLETID = OUTLETID
            FROM #AKTEMP
            WHERE ROWID = @ROWID

            SELECT @COMPANYINFOID = COMPANYINFOID
            FROM #AKTEMP
            WHERE ROWID = @ROWID

            SELECT @YEARID = YEARID
            FROM #AKTEMP
            WHERE ROWID = @ROWID

            SELECT @AREAID = AREAID
            FROM #AKTEMP
            WHERE ROWID = @ROWID

            SELECT @REPORTSTYLE = REPORTSTYLE
            FROM #AKTEMP
            WHERE ROWID = @ROWID

            SELECT @STARTDATE = CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), REPORTDATEFROM, 106)
            FROM #AKTEMP
            WHERE ROWID = @ROWID

            SELECT @ENDDATE = CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), REPORTDATETO, 106)
            FROM #AKTEMP
            WHERE ROWID = @ROWID

            SET @SQL = @SP + ' @HEADOFFICECLIENTINVOICEID = ' + @HEADOFFICECLIENTINVOICEID + ', @OUTLETID = ' + @OUTLETID + ', @COMPANYINFOID = ' + @COMPANYINFOID + ', @YEARID = ' + @YEARID + ', @AREAID = ' + @AREAID + ', @REPORTSTYLE = ' + @REPORTSTYLE + ', @STARTDATE = ''' + @STARTDATE + '''' + ', @ENDDATE = ''' + @ENDDATE + ''''

            PRINT @SQL
            PRINT @ROWID

            EXEC (@SQL) END
            SET @ROWID = @ROWID + 1
        END TRY

        BEGIN CATCH
            INSERT INTO @TAB
            SELECT @ROWID

            SET @ROWID = @ROWID + 1
        END CATCH
    END

    SELECT * FROM @TAB
```

Answer (score 0):

For processing SQL errors without affecting the overall process, you can use classic [SQL TRY-CATCH method](http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/sql-try-catch-in-sql-server-2005.aspx) with its syntax on SQL Server

Here is how I modified your SQL code

```
Declare @SP varchar(50)
Declare @RowID int
Declare @MaxRow int
Declare @HeadofficeclientinvoiceID varchar(50)
Declare @Outletid varchar(50)
Declare @CompanyInfoID varchar(50)
Declare @YearID varchar(50)
Declare @AreaID varchar(50)
Declare @ReportStyle varchar(50)
Declare @Startdate varchar(50)
Declare @Enddate varchar(50)
Declare @sql varchar(1000)


Set @SP = 'Finance_Budgeting_Against_Actual_Report'
Set @RowID = 1
Select @MaxRow = MAX(rowid) from #AKTemp

While @RowID <= @MaxRow
Begin

Select 
    @HeadofficeclientinvoiceID = HeadOfficeClientInvoicesID,
    @Outletid = Outletid,
    @CompanyInfoID = CompanyInfoID,
    @YearID = YearID,   
    @AreaID = AreaID, 
    @ReportStyle = ReportStyle,
    @Startdate = CONVERT(VARCHAR(11),ReportDateFrom, 106),
    @Enddate = CONVERT(VARCHAR(11),ReportDateTo, 106)
from #AKTemp where RowID = @RowID

Set @sql = @SP
+' @HeadofficeclientinvoiceID = '+ @HeadofficeclientinvoiceID 
+ ', @Outletid = ' + @Outletid 
+ ', @CompanyInfoID = ' + @CompanyInfoID
+ ', @YearID = ' + @YearID
+ ', @AreaID = ' + @AreaID
+ ', @ReportStyle = ' + @ReportStyle
+ ', @Startdate = ''' + @Startdate + '''' 
+ ', @Enddate = ''' + @Enddate + ''''

Set @sql = @SP

BEGIN TRY
    Exec(@sql)
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    print 'Error:'
    Print @Sql
    Print @RowID 
END CATCH;


    Set @RowID = @RowID + 1
End
```

Please note that I select the parameters from the temp table row using a single SQL SELECT statement. You can modify your code for better performance

Second, please pay attention to SQL Try...Catch block.
You can modify the CATCH block as you wish for reporting error experiencing row

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using WHILE command, an other option is to use SQL cursor which will iterate on all of the rows of the cursor. For a basic [SQL cursor tutorial](http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/cursor.aspx) please refer to given reference.

Please check the following SQL cursor code implemented for your case. You will see it is very similar to WHILE loop of yours.

```
Declare @SP varchar(50)
Declare @RowID int
Declare @MaxRow int
Declare @HeadofficeclientinvoiceID varchar(50)
Declare @Outletid varchar(50)
Declare @CompanyInfoID varchar(50)
Declare @YearID varchar(50)
Declare @AreaID varchar(50)
Declare @ReportStyle varchar(50)
Declare @Startdate varchar(50)
Declare @Enddate varchar(50)
Declare @sql varchar(1000)
Set @SP = 'Finance_Budgeting_Against_Actual_Report'


DECLARE mycursor CURSOR FAST_FORWARD FOR SELECT RowID from #AKTemp
OPEN mycursor
FETCH NEXT FROM mycursor INTO @RowID

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
-------------------------------------------
Select 
    @HeadofficeclientinvoiceID = HeadOfficeClientInvoicesID,
    @Outletid = Outletid
    @CompanyInfoID = CompanyInfoID,
    @YearID = YearID,   
    @AreaID = AreaID, 
    @ReportStyle = ReportStyle,
    @Startdate = CONVERT(VARCHAR(11),ReportDateFrom, 106),
    @Enddate = CONVERT(VARCHAR(11),ReportDateTo, 106)
from #AKTemp
where RowID = @RowID

Set @sql = @SP
+' @HeadofficeclientinvoiceID = '+ @HeadofficeclientinvoiceID 
+ ', @Outletid = ' + @Outletid 
+ ', @CompanyInfoID = ' + @CompanyInfoID
+ ', @YearID = ' + @YearID
+ ', @AreaID = ' + @AreaID
+ ', @ReportStyle = ' + @ReportStyle
+ ', @Startdate = ''' + @Startdate + '''' 
+ ', @Enddate = ''' + @Enddate + ''''

BEGIN TRY
    Exec(@sql)
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    print 'Error:'
    Print @Sql
    Print @RowID 
END CATCH;
-------------------------------------------
 FETCH NEXT FROM mycursor INTO @RowID
END

CLOSE mycursor
DEALLOCATE mycursor
```

Answer (score 0):

looks like dynamic part is unnecessary:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON

DECLARE
  @ROWID INT,
  @MAXROW INT,
  @HEADOFFICECLIENTINVOICEID VARCHAR(50),
  @OUTLETID VARCHAR(50),
  @COMPANYINFOID VARCHAR(50),
  @YEARID VARCHAR(50),
  @AREAID VARCHAR(50),
  @REPORTSTYLE VARCHAR(50),
  @STARTDATE VARCHAR(50),
  @ENDDATE VARCHAR(50),
  @SQL VARCHAR(1000),
  @crRows cursor

SET @crRows = CURSOR FAST_FORWARD
SELECT t.HeadofficeclientinvoiceID, t.Outletid, t.CompanyInfoID, 
  t.YearID, t.AreaID, t.ReportStyle, t.Startdate, t.Enddate
FROM #AKTEMP t
ORDER BY t.ROWID

OPEN @crRows

FETCH NEXT FROM @crRows
INTO @HeadofficeclientinvoiceID, @Outletid, @CompanyInfoID, 
  @YearID, @AreaID, @ReportStyle, @Startdate, @Enddate

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN TRY

  EXEC dbo.FINANCE_BUDGETING_AGAINST_ACTUAL_REPORT
    @HeadofficeclientinvoiceID = @HeadofficeclientinvoiceID,
    @Outletid       = @Outletid,
    @CompanyInfoID  = @CompanyInfoID,
    @YearID         = @YearID,
    @AreaID         = @AreaID,
    @ReportStyle    = @ReportStyle,
    @Startdate      = @Startdate
    @Enddate        = @Enddate

  FETCH NEXT FROM @crRows
  INTO @HeadofficeclientinvoiceID, @Outletid, @CompanyInfoID, 
    @YearID, @AreaID, @ReportStyle, @Startdate, @Enddate
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
  /* CATCH PART FROM @Shakeer's answer */
END

CLOSE @crRows
DEALLOCATE crRows
```

perhaps you may need to append @RowID to cursor fetch part (and select)